# JAX-RS - Spring Boot vs without Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I want to use Spring boot with JAX-RS (Jersey Implementation). If we were not using Spring Boot, we could use the following code to register all the Rest service classes

```
@ApplicationPath("/myrest")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(HelloWorld.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

This works fine in a Servlet 3.0 supported container.

But when we use Spring Boot with JAX-RS(Jersey) why do we have to extend from `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig` Why extending from `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` doesn't work?

Comment: when you use Jersey as a 'standalone' service, you put Jersey's entry point servlet in the web.xml file. This way, Jersey is able to set up dependency injection and other features. When you use Spring boot you have to comply with the way Spring does its configuration, and in this particular case you have to extend `ResourceConfig` and annotate your config class with `@Component`, otherwise Spring won't know about your services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when we use Spring Boot with JAX-RS(Jersey) why do we have to extend from `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig` Why extending from `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` doesn't work?

Because Spring Boot uses the `ResourceConfig` type as the as a service that it injects into its auto configurer, namely the [`JerseyAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.java). If you look at the source code, you will see

```
@Autowired
private ResourceConfig config;
```

From there, Sprig Boot configures the app with that instance. If a `ResourceConfig` bean is not available in the Spring context, then not auto-configuration happens.